# How to find id of element over which is popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to fetch of element's id over which is popup. I create popup inside ready function to fire on every element with rel=pop  like

```
$("[rel=pop]").popover(
{
    delay: { show: 0, hide: 200 },
    html: true,
    content:'<input id="btn" onclick=somefunction("wanted_id"); .... '
});
```

I have lot off divs with rel attribute pop and I need to find id of div ober which is popup. How to find this and call some function with that id  ? I have only one popup at time but I need div's id.

Comment: Can't get you.. sorry, but are you looking, among several popups, which one is currently visible?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("[rel=pop]").popover(
{
    delay: { show: 0, hide: 200 },
    html: true,
    content:'<input id="btn" onclick="somefunction("' + $(this).attr("id") + '");" .... '
});
```

Comment: This is not going to give me id of div with rel=pop, this gives me id of input element. I need div's id which fire up popup.

Comment: @Damir Have you tried it? I doubt it would return `btn`. At this stage that input is just a string.

Comment: I tried it, this part of code is inside ready function and this is called after when it is created on page